# Disable meteor registrationlink

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

i want to hide this registration button on the meteor accounts login page.

[image]

I found a method by setting a property in the AccountsTemplate

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: true,
  ...
});
```

Problem is, however it seems i can set this only when initializing the templates.

So i have a boolean in a meteor config json file which i would like to read:

settings.json

```
config {
  'forbidUserReg' : true
}
```

and would use this value like this:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: getUserRegConf(),
  ...
});
```

Or if possible an alternative solution to hide the registration button on the login page.

Comment: are you trying to stop users from registering (so remove the entire form) or just hide the blue registration button?

Comment: hello, atm i only want to hide this reg. button but not hide the complete login form.Users should still be able to log in but cannot create new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running meteor by calling

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

and your settings.json file has this

```
{
   "private": {
         "forbidUserReg" : true
   }
}
```

then you can just reference your settings.json file

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: Meteor.settings.private.forbidUserReg,
  ...
});
```

and toggle it whenever you want